# Adding textviews the the screen in a scrollview and I want to go down automatically

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I am creating a bunch of textviews inside a scrollview. When I create a new textview, I want the scroll view to go to the bottom so that the user doesn't have to scroll down themselves. How could I do this, do I need to it in java or xml?

Comment: Have you considered using a `ListView` rather than a `ScrollView`? A `ListView` will provide view recycling benefits and allow simple management of scroll position.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that. I only know the basics of a listview, but I do not know how to choose which view to add.. actually now I am thinking of a solution.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the effect you want you can try:

```
mScrollView.scrollTo (int x, int y)
```

which will jump to the location you indicate or a smooth scroll

```
mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(int x, int y)
```

or even

```
mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

where mScrollView is your scrollview

---

EDIT:

If you were to use a `ListView` as M.Palsish suggested you could call this on your `listview`:

```
private void scrollListViewToBottom() {
        mListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListView.setSelection(mListView.getCount());
            }
        });
    }
```